# Do formed galvanic cells counteract electrolysis?

Tags: electrochemistry, analytical-chemistry, electrolysis

I was wondering about the following:

Suppose we carry out an electrolysis with constant applied voltage. During the process, a galvanic cell should be formed by the reactants which are formed during the electrolysis. This galvanic cell should counteract the electrolysis in some way, if it gets discharged.

However is there any way to quantify this matter? I only found the comment on this website:
https://www.galvanotechnik-for-you.de/lexikon/electrolysis/

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Consider rechargeable cells.

Comment: Yeah I have thought of that, the discharge only happens really when the electrolysis is completed or halted

Answer (score 2):

This is a very good question I don't know why it has close votes. The proper term you should be searching for is called back-emf (emf=electromotive force). It was known long time at least a century ago that if you start electrolysis of water, stop it temporarily, the ammeter will show current moving in the opposite direction for a very short time. This was attributed to the formation of gaseous products at the electrodes, that formed a galvanic cell i.e., adsorbed oxygen and hydrogen want to for form water again. There are many reasons for back-emf and the formation of electrolytic products is one of them.

I assume you can read German. One of the finest works is 2-volumes on Electrochemistry History is by Ostwald (*Elektrochemie, ihre Geschichte und Lehre*). It is freely available from the Internet Archive. The English volumes also exist. Check that reference for the development of these ideas. Many electrochemical engineering textbooks will have more details on back-emf.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply, and yes, back-emf is the keyword here :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider an electrolytic cell, consisting of identical half cells with copper electrodes and the same electrolyte - e.g. $\pu{0.1 M}$ $\ce{CuSO4}$ solution, separated by a salt bridge with the same solution.

Any external nonzero DC voltage will start an electrolysis. As $\ce{Cu^2+(aq)}$ will be depleted at cathode and formed at anode, there will be formed DC voltage of galvanic cell, acting against the external voltage.

$$U = \frac{RT}{2F} \ln{\left(\frac{a(\ce{Cu^2+aq},\mathrm{anode})}{ a(\ce{Cu^2+aq},\mathrm{cathode})}\right)}$$

---

For general cases, electrolysis shifts redox systems at each electrode, the one at cathode obtaining more negative equilibrium potential, the one at anode obtaining more positive equilibrium potential.

The consequence is there is progressively needed higher voltage to keep the constant current. There is also higher threshold voltage (equal to the cell equilibrium voltage) as the electrolysis needs voltage higher than this. It was routinely observed e.g. at charging of rechargable cells.

---

When net electrolysis happens then, at the cathode, the rate of reduction is (much) higher than the rate of oxidation a vice versa at the anode. Without the external voltage and without electrode galvanic connections, both rates are equal with the zero net effect.

By other words, the rate or reduction exponentially grows with decreasing electrode potential, while the rate of oxidation exponentially grows with increasing electrode potential. Both until it hits other limitations, like ion diffusion. At given scenario, an electrode establishes such a potential that leads to particular value of the net current.

Comment: Is this only the case when both cells are identical or is this the general case?

Comment: Yes and no. It depends on what you mean by "this".

Comment: Let me rephrase a bit: Consider electrolysis of a Zn/Cu system. If we start with a 1M solution of zinc sulfate and 1M copper sulfate, we need >1.100 V to start electrolysis.  After a while, for example zinc ions are at 0.5 M and copper at 1.5 M and the cell voltage is at 1.114V. But as long as the voltage is always greater than the decomposition voltage, only electrolysis happens. For example, the system could not discharge (reverse reaction) while this voltage is applied, is that correct?

Comment: It is and is not correct - see the A update.

Comment: Poutnik, How can the rate of reduction be not the same as rate of oxidation. For each electron leaving, there must be one electron entering the electrolytic cell?

Comment: *How can the rate of reduction be not the same as rate of oxidation* - On the **same** electrode.

Comment: You mean in the absence of any external current.

Comment: As reversible processes, that are on macro level at static equilibrium, are at dynamic equilibrium on atomic/molecular/ionic level.

Comment: Or absence of potential drift, at which both rates just converge to the same value.

Comment: Yes indeed, but that is not my point. I am trying to confirm if you meant that the rate of reduction and oxidation is the same on the *same* electrode, in the absence of any externally applied potential.

Comment: At absence of external current or forced potential AND constant electrode potential, both nonzero oxidation and reduction rates on the same electrode are equal.

Comment: Btw shouldn’t it be the other way around? Rate of oxidation should increase when the potential gets lower (more negative)?

Comment: No, it should. Forced low potential means raised chemical potential of electrons, forcing reduction by  accepting electrons.  And vice versa.